# How to combine multiple datasets into a new dataset?

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 power bi datasets deployed into the workspace.

I want to create a new report that makes use of both the datasets. In a new report when I choose 1 of the datasets, then the transform query button gets grayed out. I'm not sure how to choose the 2nd dataset. Does power bi have the ability to choose multiple datasets for a new report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to query across multiple Datasets is currently in preview.

[Using DirectQuery for Power BI datasets and Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services)

Or you can build a third dataset that imports some of the same source data as the other two.

Comment: I understand the live connection means it uses the underlying tabular model. And that direct query means it queries underlying dataset (example: sql server) for each visual. What does direct query to a live dataset (model) mean?

Comment: It's DirectQuery.  It queries the underlying (remote) Power BI Dataset or AAS Tabular model for each visual.  But it's a composite model so it can have multiple DirectQuery data sources and also import and dual tables.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models  In Live Connect your pbix doesn't have a local model _at all_.

Comment: When report has its own dataset or points to a live dataset then it has high performance. Whereas when it DirectQuery sql sever db then I observe slow performance. How does the direct query to another model behave in terms of performance?

Comment: Somewhere inbetween.  For single-source queries you get import-like performance.  But cross-source queries are expensive. See general composite model per guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models#performance-implications

Comment: Above link only talks about DirectQuery with sql. It doesn't say about using DirectQuery with powerbi dataset. Is there any reference for that?

Comment: DirectQuery doesn't only work with SQL-based sources.  So wherever you see "SQL query" it really means "SQL or DAX or Kusto, etc... Query".

Comment: I created a report and selected an existing pbi dataset via the data hub dropdown. It shows me that I'm connected live to the pbi dataset. Now I'm unable to select another dataset. How to choose 2nd dataset?

Comment: Enable the preview feature per the docs.

Comment: Assuming I connect to 2 live datasets having the same tables, then does it combine the table data into 1 table or show as 2 separate entities?

Comment: They would be separate.